# How to fix full height minute and hour hand in analog clock in android studio?

Tags: android

I'm developing an android application that contains a simple analog clock with black background, so I had placed my own clock dial. But when I place my minute and hour hand, this is the original one:

[image]

Edited the problem is in drawable not code.

The result:

[image]

What I expect:

[image]

This is my code:

```
        <AnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/analogClock"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:dial="@drawable/clock_dail"
            android:hand_minute="@drawable/clock_minute"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />
```

Comment: This question is quiet broad. Best to provide the code you are using to generate the clock.

Comment: @H4kor i edited it now and i added my code used for clock

Comment: Add images, please. Drive takes forever with no result. And don't forget to provide your custom drawable.

Comment: @Farid I added one, i found the problem not in code its in the drawable the original one in the question is have a line with transparent top and bottom i tried too to make a new copy of it with custom color but not working, any ideas? thanks

Comment: In the original question, you've added two images. One image was what it looks like and the other was what it should look like. Can you add those pictures, I want to see the problem.

Comment: @Farid i added them now